# sending a value to another function but not as a parameter

Tags: c, function

I defined r as in the main function:

```
srand(time(NULL));
r = rand() %1024 + 1;
```

and I use r in another function I called in main function.

```
int make_a_guess(int trial, int min, int max)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=trial; i++)
    {
        int guess;
        printf("(Trial: %d) Make a guess between %d and %d: ",i,min,max);
        scanf("%d\n",&guess);
        if(guess < r)
            min = guess;
        else if(guess < r)
            max = guess;
        else
            printf("You win!");
    }
}
```

But function can't find r I think.To prevent errors I declare "int r;" above functions but with that I get "control reaches end of non-void function" error.Because of instructions I couldn't define r in the function,I have to define it in the main function.Also I can't send it as a parameter.

Comment: `int make_a_guess(...)` The error says that `make_a_guess` is defined to return an `int`, but there is no `return` in it. As for the rest, please post real, compilable code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I add return min after if and return max after else if but again it didn't work.It says expected expression for that part.These are instructions so I couldn't change int as void .

Comment: Describing code in words is not useful. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65032608/edit) the real code into the question.

Comment: The 'control reaches end of non-void function' is an error unrelated to the previous 'undefined variable `r`' error.  It is simply another error that you need to fix as well as defining `r` as a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found the solution.I rearrenge the function like that:

```
int make_a_guess(int trial, int min, int max){
for(int i=1; i<=trial; i++)
{
    int guess;
    printf("(Trial: %d) Make a guess between %d and %d: ",i,min,max);
    scanf("%d",&guess);
    if(guess < r)
    {
        min = guess;
        continue;
    }
    else if(guess > r)
    {
        max = guess;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You win!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
printf("You lost!\n");
return 0;
```

Comment: If you are not returning anything useful, why the int return type?  Would not void be more appropriate?